# Are ojdbc versions backward compatible?

Tags: jdbc, ojdbc

We recently started having problems with ojdbc14, since dba's had added `sqlnet.allowed_logon_version=11` to the database configuration. Hence we needed to upgrade our JDBC client to ojdbc6.

My question is would upgrade to new JDBC driver impact our application (may be datatypes etc) in any way?

Oracle seems vague about it though they say,

> We take backward compatibility very seriously.

Has anybody encountered any problems post JDBC version upgrade?

Comment: Do you not have dev / and or staging environments where you can run your test suite? To see if there are issues?

Comment: Yes we do but I could not think of good regression testing to prove its not going to create any issue in current code in future. That's why asking opinion if any body had any issue.

Comment: ojdbc14 and ojdbc6 doesn't say anything about the version of the driver (just for which Java version they are). You need to know the version of your previous driver and the new driver and check the release notes to know if anything changed.